# Understanding F-test to compare variances (R's var.test)

Tags: r, sampling, p-value, inference, f-distribution

I gave run the following codes in R console:

```
#for built-in matrix ToothGrowth
tooth.1mg <- subset(ToothGrowth, dose==1)
var.test(len~supp,data=tooth.1mg,alternative="two.sided")
```

I have found the result:

```
F test to compare two variances
data:  len by supp 

F = 2.4176, num df = 9, denom df = 9, p-value = 0.2046

alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1 

95 percent confidence interval:
0.6004952 9.7332038 

sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
2.41759
```

But I do not understand what the result expresses. Is that we fail to reject `null hypotheses` since `p-value>sig.level`? If so, then I found in most cases by implying the command `var.test` that we  fail to reject `null hypotheses` since  `p-value > sig.level`. Or, if I focus on confidence interval, it doesn't include hypothesized value which concludes that we reject `null hypotheses` in favor of `alternative hypotheses` at 0.05 significance level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation (type `?var.test` or `help("var.test")` in the console) or look at the output carefully, you will see that it tests whether the *ratio* between the two variances is 1 (and not whether the *difference* is 0). The confidence interval therefore does include the hypothesized value (namely 1) and is perfectly coherent with the *p* value. In both cases, you fail to reject $H_0$ at the specified error level. See also [a previous question on this test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31454/how-to-interpret-the-confidence-interval-of-a-variance-f-test-using-r)

Incidentally, the CI is also pretty wide and you have apparently very few observations. I don't know what you are trying to achieve but it might that this test doesn't tell you much about your data.